# Changing one value in a Dynamic 2D boolean array seemingly changes the value at a different place in a different array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I have two dynamically allocated boolean arrays of size height * width, that I allocated / initialized with...

```
bool ** visited; 
bool ** inQueue; 
visited = new bool * [height];
inQueue = new bool * [height];
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    visited[i] = new bool(width);
    inQueue[i] = new bool(width);
}

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        visited[i][j] = false;
        inQueue[i][j] = false;
    }
```

And at the end of my program I clear up that memory with...

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    delete [] visited[i];
    delete [] inQueue[i];
}
delete [] visited;
delete [] inQueue;
```

But, in between, I get a weird condition where various values in visited's  0th column become true even though they are not being directly changed.

An example of this behavior is:

```
    . . . . . . . . . . . X . . . . .       0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
    . . . . . . # . # . X X X . # . .       0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 
    . . . . . . # . . # X X X X # . .       0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
    . . . . . . # . X X X X X X # . .       0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
    . . . . . . # # # # # X X X # . .       0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
    . # . . . . . . . . # X X X X @ .       0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
    . # . . . . . . . . # X X X X . .       1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
    . # . . . . . . . . # X X X . . .       0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
    . G # . . . # # # . # X X . # . .       0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 
    . # . . . . . . . . . X . . . . .       0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
    . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . . .       0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .       0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .       0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .       0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    . . . . . . # . . . . . . . # . .       0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
    . . . . . . # . . . . . . . # . .       0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
    . . . . . . # . . . . . . . # . .       0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 

    [6][0] @ 205: 0
    Added Eastern Pos: (16, 5)
    [6][0] @ 208: 1
    [6][0] @ 210: 1
    ...
```

This is my output. As you can see, the position in visited[6][0] becomes true on what I've labeled in my output after line 205, while adding the eastern position. That code for that change is here:

```
cout << "[6][0] @ 205: " << visited[6][0] << endl;
cout << "Added Eastern Pos: (" << (east % width) << ", " << (int)floor(east / width) << ")\n";
inQueue[(int)floor(east / width)][east % width] = true;
cout << "[6][0] @ 208: " << visited[6][0] << endl;
xVal.addToQueue(to_string(east % width));
```

Specifically on the third line I change the value of inQueue, and then immediately afterwards (as seen in the block above) visited[6][0] has changed to true. Keep in mind that

> (int)floor(east / width)

is actually 5, and

> east % width

is 16. So, to me it makes no sense whatsoever that visited would be changed. This happens incrementally throughout my programs run, always with values of the 0th column being changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: `bool(width)`-> `bool[width]`?

Comment: After using `new` you should use `delete`, not `delete []`!!

Comment: I get erroneous behavior if I don't use delete []. In terms of memory, what's the downside to using delete [] over delete if it's incorrect in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `visited[i] = new bool(width)`, you allocate a single boolean value, not an array of booleans. Henceforth, when expecting an array of `width` elements, which actually consists only of one, you exceed array bounds and get undefined behaviour (and that's what you see in your output).

See the difference:

```
int main() {
    int width =20;
    int sizeofBool = sizeof(bool(width)); // -> 1
    int sizeOfBoolArray = sizeof(bool[width]); // -> 20
}
```

So write `visited[i] = new bool[width]` (and also for `inQueue`), and you should at least get ahead.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the quick explanation. This worked for me, and I feel silly for letting such a little error mess me up for so long.